# How to pass data between view controller in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The select item is a slider. When I click the slider It will pass the data to Second VC (WebViewController). but how to pass data from first view controller to second view controller in objective-c? Sorry, This is my first time coding objective C.

First VC .m file

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arraySliderProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UIViewController *controller = nil;


    switch (indexPath.row)
    {

        case 0:
        {
            WebViewController *WebViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
            //error: No visible @interface for "WebViewController" declares the selector 'alloc'
            WebViewController.data = arraySliderProducts[indexPath.row][@"title"]; //pass this link value
            //error: Property 'data' not found on object of type 'WebViewController'
            [self.navigationController pushViewController: WebViewController animated:YES];
        }..
```

Second VC .m file

```
@interface WebViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *data;
```

Second VC .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    NSString *data;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points to note:

1: This is not the way to initiate a view controller to show/present in your app.

2: You should declare your `NSString *data` in your SecondVC's `.h` file.

Now point 1 solutions is to change your code with below in your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`: function

```
switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case 0:
    {
        // By Default storyboard name is "Main". Change it if you you have different name in your project
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

        // Now instantiate your view controller with its identifier on this storyboard object. 
        // Note: don't forget to set viewControllers' identifier
        WebViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"WebViewController"];

        // Now Pass your value 
        WebViewController.data = arraySliderProducts[indexPath.row][@"title"]; 

        //Finally push this object on your navigation stack
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: WebViewController animated:YES];
    }... 
}
```

Comment: I try to add NSString *data; inside or outside @interface on .h file. but still getting the error.

Comment: This error usually happens when you create an object where object creation is simply not allowed.

Comment: Ok, I updated .h file code to the question. not allowed?

Comment: now plz tell me what error you are getting? You have edited your first comment

Comment: Sorry, Its the same. Property 'data' not found on object of type 'WebViewController' and  Unexpected interface name 'WebViewController': expected expression

Comment: did you post complete `.h` file code in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153918/discussion-between-m-zubair-shamshad-and-wan-jern).

Answer (score 0):

try as

```
//Your class and obj name is same so You are getting this type of error

        WebViewController *VC = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
    //OR
        WebViewController *VC= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewController"];


        VC.data = arraySliderProducts[indexPath.row][@"title"]; 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: VC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Property 'data' not found on object of type 'WebViewController'. What i need to add in second VC?

Comment: You dont need to add anything in SecondVC just change the VArible name of "WebViewController" as try above